# java.lang.VerifyError and Product Flavors

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I have an Android app with two product flavors (pro & free):

```
productFlavors {
    pro {
       ...
    }
    free {
       ...
    }
```

There is a class (ProModelImpl) implemented differently in both flavors. There are two separate ProModelImpl.java files in folder trees:

```
/app/free/java/com/myapp/models
/app/pro/java/com/myapp/models
```

This class is used by another class (ProModel.java) located in the main source tree:

```
/app/main/java/com/myapp/models
```

All works fine on my devices, but **some** users got a strange exception (I see this via Crashlytics):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: com/myapp/models/ProModelImpl
       at com.myapp.models.ProModel.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at com.myapp.models.ProModel.access$200(Unknown Source)
       at com.myapp.models.ProModel$InstanceHolder.(Unknown Source)
       at com.myapp.models.ProModel.getInstance(Unknown Source)
       at com.myapp.App.createModels(Unknown Source)
       at com.myapp.App.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4684)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Sometime deleting the build folder and recompiling helps. Sometime not. I am currently having this problem with Build Tools v23.0.2 and Gradle v2.4.

Any ideas why this could be and how to fix?